# Cursor jumping to top and bottom of page for multiple browsers in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: mouse

I have a new machine and install of 20.04. When I scroll through browser pages using mouse wheel, the cursor will suddenly jump to the top (sometimes bottom) of the page. I have tried firefox, chrome and edge and they all act the same. It doesn't seem to happen with all websites.

I normally use a wireless mouse but this also happens with hardwired mouse.

I tried turning on natural scrolling but that did not make a difference.

This is a dual-boot PC and the problem does not exist when I boot to windows.