# Browser scroll jumping without mouse input (Firefox and Chrome) after package update in 20.04

Tags: 20.04, mouse, browser

After using 20.04 on this machine for months with no problems, following a full package update today, the browser scroll position jumps around, usually to the top, without any mouse input and even with the mouse disconnected (Firefox and Chrome). It jumps once every few seconds, but sometimes acts normally for a few minutes, but then resumes the bad behavior. Reading or interacting with a web page is extremely difficult when this happens.

This behavior has been described before, but no explanations or solutions have been forthcoming.

[Cursor jumping to top and bottom of page for multiple browsers in Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1310675/cursor-jumping-to-top-and-bottom-of-page-for-multiple-browsers-in-ubuntu-20-04)

[All browsers are jumping around web page after updating to 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1348588/all-browsers-are-jumping-around-web-page-after-updating-to-20-04)

[sudden anomalies with scrolling in all browsers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1384473/sudden-anomalies-with-scrolling-in-all-browsers)

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/RxPBmFD8qr/

Answer (score 4):

Installing the [GNOME Shell Extension Alt+Tab Scroll Workaround](https://github.com/lucasresck/gnome-shell-extension-alt-tab-scroll-workaround) extension fixed this issue for me. More info on the issue is in the README of the repository.

Comment: Actually this did not fix the issue...

Comment: For me, this does mostly fix the issue, however it ignores the first scoll input after an ALT+TAB.  That's much less annoying than the original bug, but still somewhat annoying.

Comment: this extension fixed the issue in my case (fedora 39)