# Jumping scroll problem

Tags: google-chrome

I scroll with my mouse in PHPStorm or Gedit or any other scrollable window, then I switch to Chrome. When I try to scroll in Chrome, my screen will instantly page up/down several pages - approx the same ammount as I scrolled in previous window. May be it is a problem of Chrome (I reported there too). It occurs only in Chrome.

Ubuntu: 22.04.2 LTS
gnome: 42.9
WS: X11

Linux r4000 5.19.0-50-generic #50-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Jul 10 18:24:29 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: try the answer mentioned here:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404355/browser-scroll-jumping-without-mouse-input-firefox-and-chrome-after-package-up